# Беда в режиме Deferred у главной камеры

Tags: unity3d, камера

Сегодня заметил такой глюк:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Очень долго пытался понять, с чем это возникает, оказалось, что когда включаю `Deferred` у `MainCamera`.

Что это за беда такая и как ее решить не выключая режим `Deferred`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена и заключалась она, в регулировке `Shadow Bias` в основном освещении.